# Two matrices Overlap diagonal transformation

Tags: matlab, matrix

How to calculate overlap area between 2 matrices with a different dimension?
For example 600X300 and 600X650. We need to calculate the overlap area from top left corner to bottom right corner and second matrix from the opposite direction.

We already make first part as you can see in the code below .

```
[fix_r,fix_c] = size(fix_img);
[float_r,float_c] = size(float_img);
diagLineFix = hypot(size(fix_img,1), size(fix_img,2));
diagLineFlt = hypot(size(float_img,1), size(float_img,2));
diagLine = min(diagLineFix,diagLineFlt);
end_rang = 2*diagLine;
step = 10;
for i = 1:step:end_rang
    float_img_t =0;
    fix_img_t = 0;
    if i <fix_r && i < fix_c
        float_img_t = float_img(1:i+1,1:i+1);
        fix_img_t = fix_img(fix_r - (i):end,fix_c - (i):end);
        if disply == 1 %display the output
            registration_display(fix_img_t,float_img_t);
        end
    end %% more code should be here to complete diagonal transformation 
end
```

Note the two overlap area should have the same dimension.

Comment: what do you mean with "overlap area"? did you check already matlab built-in functions such as corr2? (might be irrelevant, but just in case).

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to apply diagonal transformation is using `imwarp`.

1. we need to create transformation matrix first. we need to set [image: t_x]
   and [image: t_y] as below image.

[image]

2. Define the spatial space for reference and floating image using `imref2d`.
3. Apply the transformation on the floating image using `imwarp`.

We need to set [image: t_x]
and [image: t_y] with the desired value to transform the floating image in diagonal direction.

```
cb = checkerboard(40,20);
cb_ref = imref2d(size(cb));
background = zeros(2000);
bg_ref = imref2d(size(background));
tx = 100;
ty = 100;
T = [1 0 0;0 1 0;tx ty 1];
tform_t = affine2d(T);
[out,out_ref] = imwarp(cb,cb_ref,tform_t);
imshowpair(out,out_ref,background,bg_ref)
```